# CSS is not applied on footer angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been struggling with this for two days now, though it looks very simple.
As you see the footer i created in the picture here:

[image: picture]

I have two problems:

- I cannot seem to apply any `css` modifications on the footer inside the text ("Capgemini newcomer application")
- I cannot add a line separating the rest of the page from the footer without intercepting the logo or applying a margin between the page content and the footer like shown in the next photo:

[image: picture 2]

**HTML code**

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar">
  <img src="img/Imag.png" class="test2" />
  <div class="text"> Capgemini Newcomer Application </div>
  <img src="img/Test3.png" class="test"/>
</ion-footer>
```

**CSS code**

```
.bar {

    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FBC02D;

}

.bar .test {
    float: right;
    clear: left;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 130px;
    max-height: 100px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 2px;
}


.bar .test2 {

    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.bar .text {

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 6;
    bottom: 2px;

}
```

**EDIT**

After doing the modifications mentioned below, i got this:

[image: picture 3]

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle

Comment: 1.) can you provide a demo page where we can look at the rendered template? `ion-footer-bar` is a directive that can modify the actual HTML output
2.) the second question seems to be a problem with the logo (transparency) and nothing you can fix with pure CSS.

Comment: cant you give the width for your bar in percentages(75%) ?

Comment: No. the whole bar will shrink, along with the pictures

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-footer-bar ng-class="{'bar': true}">...</ion-footer>
```

Comment: OP has not stated anything about AngularJS here.

Comment: there was an `angular` tag in it (and that's why i answered it), it's edited as of now (you may want to check the edit history)

Comment: @A.Sharma OP obviously uses Ionic Framework, which integrates AngularJS.

Comment: Please can you explain what you answered? also It does not work :/

Comment: use `ng-class="{'bar': true}"` instead of `class` and that should work, `true` in it (generally that's the place for some expressions/conditions which when evaluates to `true` the `css` class `bar` gets applied) will apply the `css` and `false` won't

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your CSS that don't work like you would expect:

```
.bar {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px; /* doesn't do anything for position: absolute */
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FBC02D; /* <-- this will always add the border outside the footer */
}

.bar .test {
    float: right;
    clear: left;
    position: fixed; /* <-- either you float it, or you position it fixed - both together don't make sense */
    max-width: 130px;
    max-height: 100px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 2px;
}

.bar .test2 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    bottom: 20px; /* <-- "bottom" on a non-positioned element doesn't do anything */
}

.bar .text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 6; /* <-- font size needs a unit like "px" or "pt" */
    bottom: 2px; /* same as above, this should probably be margin-bottom instead */
}
```

Cleaned up, it could look like this:

```
.bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
}

.bar .test {
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 130px;
    max-height: 100px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 2px;
}

.bar .test2 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bar .text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 6pt;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FBC02D;
}
```

This will still overlap the logo with the border, but that's a problem that you need to fix in the logo image.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will update the results but still I cannot edit the text to center it